# modifying key's name in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, shutil, python-os

I am trying to write a python script so that I can find all `sub_directories` called `'something'` within a parent directory.Then I would like to rename the `sub directories` and move them somewhere else. So far I have my code as:

```
import os, shutil,fnmatch

match = {}
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('test'):
    #print root
    #print dirnames
    #print filenames
    for i in fnmatch.filter(dirnames,'find'):
        #print os.path.join(root,dirnames[0])
        print root
        #match.append(root)
        match[root]=dirnames[0]
```

call match gives me something like `{'test\a': 'find'......}`. I would like to modify the key value of the dictionary so that it looks like `{'a':'find'...` so essentially I am trying to get rid of the name of the parent directory. I thought about converting to string and use split but seems to be not so efficient.

Comment: or better question, is there a way I can store the path name without including the first directory. I am only working with level two path (so something like test/a/find)

Comment: I think `os.path.basename(dirname)` should do the trick for you...

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور yes it would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `dirname` without the `parent` directory name, use `os.path.basename`, this way:

```
>>> dirname = 'C:\\Users\\myUsers\\Videos'
>>> os.path.basename(dirname)
'Videos'
```

EDIT: in response to OP comments,

Given:

`dirname = 'C:\\Users\\myUsers\\Videos'`

And you want to get new folder name as `myUsers_Videos`, here is one way:

```
>>> os.path.basename('_'.join(os.path.split(dirname)))
'myUsers_Videos'
```

Comment: yea but I also need the folder above \vidoes for renaming purpose.

Comment: @xiaocheng Do you want it as `absolute` path or just name of folder?

Comment: for instance the folder I want to find is called 'find' and its path is test/a/find, I want to rename the find folder as a_find and move it somewhere else. sorry for the confusion

Comment: so the new folder name will be a combination of both folders names, right?

Comment: I was able to obtain what I want using copytree from shutil module.